# What are Block Producer URLs and Ports (Server/Wallet) if any?

Tags: block-producer, mainnet

I assume that we should expect to execute the same commands on a main-net as we are executing them on a test-net. For example, to create an account, we do the following:

```
$cleos --wallet-url http://wallet:5555 -u http://server:7777 create account eosio mynewaccount {MyNewAccount owner Public Key} {MyNewAccount active Public Key}
```

What are the http://wallet:5555 and http://server:7777 equivalents for block-producers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Correct**, same commands used on test nets to work on the main net.

Typically the port `:8888` is used.

The `--wallet-url http://wallet:5555` switch is used to grab your keys, therefore this depends entirely where you keep them. You could continue to keep your keys at that address, I'm guessing it's a local one and you're using a guide like 
[EOSDocs.io](http://eosdocs.io)? This is something specific to you and your environment.

The `-u http://server:77777` references the Block Producers endpoint which is a gateway into the network, this will change for main net. What you put in here depends entirely on the Block Producers online when it launches, at the moment this endpoint connects to the Jungle testnet `-u http://dolphin.eosblocksmith.io:8888` etc.

Main stream Block Producers will all advertise what to put in the `-u` switch when the main net comes online.

Comment: Thank you for Jungle TestNet reference, I will try it for testing. Also, I would accept this as an answer, but waiting for someone to come up with the list when the BPs establish the main-net. EDIT: accepted given the -u switch.

Answer (score 0):

There always has a helpful command that goes with `--help`:

```
cleos --help
Command Line Interface to EOSIO Client
Usage: cleos [OPTIONS] SUBCOMMAND

Options:
  -h,--help                   Print this help message and exit
  -u,--url TEXT=http://localhost:8888/
                              the http/https URL where nodeos is running
  --wallet-url TEXT=http://localhost:8900/
                              the http/https URL where keosd is running
```

As you can see wallet-url will be the parameter for wallet and u is for BP (nodeos)

Comment: Would accept as an answer, but first-come first-serve.